# Evaluating Potentials using Galpy

Tags: galaxy, python, galactic-dynamics, galactic-halo, galactic-evolution

I am trying to model galactic disks. From the past research we have discovered that the halo follows the logarithmic potential, the disk follows the Miyamoto-Nagai potential and the bulge follows the Hernquist potential. I have the $R$ and $z$ coordinates of a sample of stars divided into halo, bulge and disk stars and I am trying to compute the potentials of these potential using [galpy](https://github.com/jobovy/galpy)'s `galpy.potential.evaluatePotentials(Pot, R, z, phi=None, t=0.0, dR=0, dphi=0)`.

However, it looks like the potentials are defaulted as non axis symmetric during initialization since I am getting the error message as shown in the image.

[image]

Is there a way to make this work?

Coding the potentials is one way to get around the problem, however, before resorting to this option, I needed to check whether there are solutions available already.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Never used `galpy` before and not sure how your doing your import and definition (can you edit the Q to show this please?) but if I do a `from galpy.potential import LogarithmicHaloPotential ; halo = LogarithmicHaloPotential()` then doing a `halo.isNonAxi` returns False so it has that attribute.

Comment: Looks like a temporary bug in the code. I uninstalled galpy and reinstalled it. That worked!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, I believe the issue here was that you didn't instantiate the potential. That is, you probably tried to do

```
from galpy.potential import LogarithmicHaloPotential, evaluatePotentials
evaluatePotentials(LogarithmicHaloPotential,1.,0.)
```

rather than

```
from galpy.potential import LogarithmicHaloPotential, evaluatePotentials
lp= LogarithmicHaloPotential() # specific instance with default parameters
evaluatePotentials(lp,1.,0.)
```

Please don't hesitate to open an Issue or Discussion at the GitHub page or join the slack community there: https://github.com/jobovy/galpy. I don't usually monitor stackexchange.

Comment: *Welcome to Astronomy SE!*